# Wordpress doesn't seem to correctly map POST data

Tags: php, html, wordpress

here's my problem :

I have a .php file within my wordpress that do the following thing :

- with a form asks a NAME and to the user
- posts the data to this same page (action="")
- if NAME is not empty, then do something, else ask for the NAME again

Here's the code :

```
function loginForm(){
echo'
<div id="loginform">
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>Please enter your name to continue:</p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <input type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Enter" />
</form>
</div>
';
}


if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != ""){
   //do smth
}
else{
        echo '<span class="error">Please type in a name</span>';
    }
}
```

But here's the problem : when i click without entering any name, then it's fine, it works as expected : it returns the same page with an error message. HOWEVER, if I enter any name, it returns me "Page Not Found", and the POST request fails (404)

What could be happening so such a thing happens ?

PS : excuse me for my probably bad english

Comment: Instead of `action = ""` maybe try `SERVER['PHP_SELF']` as discussed here: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html

Comment: It is also better to use some kind of front-end validation such that if `name` is not provided, the FORM does not POST the data. This will save trips to the server processing unusable data. `jQuery` has validation plugins that work really well.

Comment: Since it is a Wordpress application, can you build the form element using one of the Wordpress plugins?  Just a thought.

Comment: Adam T: I have to do this back-end because i starts a php session (it's a mini chat that I want to integrate to one of my wordpress page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
```

This will cause issues specific to wordpress, it is a reserved field name.
so change the name.

```
<input type="text" name="aname" id="name" />
```

Should work with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

in WordPress you need to specify an `action`. This should work:

```
action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>
```

Comment: But how come does it work on some of my other pages, and on this one if I don't specify "name" ?

Comment: I guess it depends on your structure. You would have to inform us with more specifics like file location and such. Keep in mind that when name is blank, it sends the request to whatever URL you are currently on.